# JQuery: How to switch image back and forth?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="listing ref_1">
    ...
    <div><img src="toggleON.png" /></div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="listing ref_2">
    ...
    <div><img src="toggleON.png" /></div>
    ...
</div>

<div class="listing ref_3">
    ...
    <div><img src="toggleON.png" /></div>
    ...
</div>
```

What I want to do is programmatically change the `toggleON.png` image to `toggleOFF.png`.

I'm trying to use the following code to do so but it's not working:

```
$('.ref_2').src("toggleOFF.png");
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong because the code above doesn't work.

Also, is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

'.ref_2' points to the div, you'll have to get to the image within the div

```
$('.ref_2 img').attr("src","toggleOFF.png");
```

would probably do it for you.

Comment: you probably needed to refresh, i had it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the img tag in side .ref_2

```
$('.ref_2 img').attr("src","toggleOFF.png");
```

It might be better though to put the image definition in css and swap classes.

```
<style>
.toggleOn div{
   background: url('toggleOn.png') no-repeat;
}
.toggleOff div{
   background: url('toggleOff.png') no-repeat;
}
</script>

<div class="listing ref_1 toggleOn">
    ...
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="listing ref_2 toggleOn">
    ...
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>

<div class="listing ref_3 toggleOn">
    ...
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>

<script>
$('.ref_2').removeClass('toggleOn').addClass('toggleOff');
</script>
```

This makes it really easy to change the image and lets you use the class as a state toggle if you need to check on it later.

Also it looks like you are using ref_# as a unique identifier, if so then it would be better to make it the ID of the div, will speed up jQuery's ability to find the element.

Comment: How would I put it in CSS if this is better?

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is put both images in my main document in a hidden div, like:

```
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden">
  <img id="toggleON" src="/whatever/toggleON.png" .../>
  <img id="toggleOFF" src="/whatever/toggleOff.png" .../>
</div>
```

That way they're both in the browser's cache.  Then, to toggle an image from one to the other, you can do something like:

```
$(".whatever img").replaceWith($("#toggleON").clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to put both image on absolute position, with the *default* one is set to the front (Using z-index property).

On mouse hover, you can hide the one in the front and the *toggled-off* image will showed up. The advantage of using this method is you could actually use animation technique to make it even smoother. It's what I did [here](http://www.lumenlite.co.id/products). (It would be better if you have an additional wrapper div and set the mouse hover event on it)